# Saving complicated object to database

Tags: java, database, class, interface

I want to save this object to db, but I don't know how should I do it..

```
 

    public class Board {
      private String name;
      private Sticker sticker;
     Board(String name, Sticker sticker){
      this.name=name;
      this.sticker = sticker;
    }

    }

    public interface Sticker {
      public void doSomething();
    }

    public class FreeSticker implements Sticker {
      @Override
      public void doSomething(){
       System.out.println("I'm freeSticker");
      }
    }
    public class ProSticker implements Sticker {
      @Override
      public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm proSticker");
      }
    }
```

And now I want to save my new Board object with set name and some Sticker (lets say FreeSticker) to Database. How? name is easy, because in every db we have String type, but what about Sticker? I know, I can create another table for FreeSticker and ProSticker, but it is complicated when for example we have more than 2 implementations of Sticker.. I'm not asking for super solution, but please give me links for some tutorials with it, because I can't find anything about this. Thanks :)

Comment: Your `Sticker` does not contain any attribute nor it changes the attribute of `Board`. But in case it changes any attribute of Board object, even then the schema will remain the same for Board table.

Comment: Your `Sticker` implementations do not have state. What do you plan to save?

Comment: For general `ORM` info have a look at http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/

Comment: If you want to store the objects but don't need to use database features (i.e. using SQL to access them) then you could just use serlialization to a blob. Search for serialization in the standard Java tutorial.

Comment: Oh, it is only example, you can assume that Sticker implementations have state, for example some field content or name..

Answer (score 0):

Your table should contain a column for each state value. In your case there are two, plus its usually nice to include a unique ID field as a primary key. So, in PostgreSQL ...

```
CREATE TABLE board (
    id       SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name     text,
    sticker  boolean);
```

Or if you plan/expect to have multiple stickers.

```
CREATE TABLE sticker (
    id       SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name     text);

CREATE TABLE board (
    id       SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name     text,
    sticker  int REFERENCES sticker(id) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Maybe it should be that sticker contains field board int references board(id) NOT NULL, not board has field sticker.. Because board can has many stickers, stickers is only in one board. ?